# Handling large amounts of denormalized read model updates in CQRS

Tags: mongodb, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm designing a CQRS event-sourced system (not my first) where my read models are denormalized and stored in a read-optimized document database (MongoDb). Nothing special. Now this particular read model, is a document that contains a user id and a potentially large array of groups that the user is a member of:

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "userName": "aaron",
  "groups": [
    {
      "groupId": 1,
      "name": "group 1"
    },
    {
      "groupId": 2,
      "name": "group 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

There could be 10's of thousands of users that are a member of a single group (just as one example: imagine a group that *every* staff member is a member of).

Keeping in mind the reason I'm using CQRS in the first place, is that I *need* to scale my reads (or rather, handle my reads differently given the need to avoid lots of joins), and I'm *expecting* a significant volume of writes. This isn't the *only* reason I'm using CQRS and event-sourcing, but it is one major catalyst.

Now the problem I have is when someone updates a group name, (which I'm predicting will happen quite frequently) my read model needs updating. This means a single user modification to a single piece of data, is going to cause 10's of thousands of updates in my read store.

I am well aware of all the techniques I can apply to handle dispatching the update to avoid temporal coupling, however I am concerned with the *number* of documents that will be updated per single user modification.

I've read several SO answers that ask this exact type of question, and most answers suggest that either you need to strike a balance, or not worry about the mass updates. But IMO, this is not really an option. There really is no balance to be had in this type of read model (any re-modelling of the document would still necessitate the group name appearing **just as many times**, no matter how it's re-modelled), and simply accepting the mass quantities of updates is counter-productive to the idea of the super fast read store, as it will now be under severe load due to the constant updates that are almost always going to be queued up. Essentially what will happen, is the denormalizing process is going to bottleneck, and the queue is going to grow over time (until there is some respite from users updating group names), and reading will become slow as a side-effect.

Before anyone jumps on me and asks whether I *know* that this bottleneck will occur, the answer is "it should, but obviously I can't be sure". But, based on knowing how many changes are made in the existing system that I'm replacing, and, keeping in mind this is not the only type of model in the document database that will require updating, I have pretty good cause to be concerned. As I said, there are several other read models - that may not have the same number of updates - but will nevertheless add to the write load in the read store. And, the read store can only take so many writes.

I can think of two solutions (one dumb, one not so dumb):

1. Store a version in each document, and to **not** update the read
   model when an event occurs. Then when a read occurs for a particular
   document, I check for staleness, and if the version is stale (due to
   a proceeding command), I apply the last change to that document
   before storing and returning it. However, my instinct tells me that 
   eventually every document is going to get updated regardless, and
   this is just adding additional overhead to the read. I also have no
   idea how the versioning would actually work
2. Use a relational read model and have the single join. This seems the
   most sensible option, as I would just update the join table, and all
   is good. But the reads wouldn't be as fast, and it just feels a bit
   more inferior to a pure select * from tablename approach.

**My question:**

Are there any standard techniques for combating this type of issue? Is the second option I offered simply the best I can hope for?

I would honestly have thought that this type of problem would occur all the time in a CQRS event-sourced systems, where denormalized data needs to be kept in sync, but there seems to be a lack of discussion about it in the community which leads me to believe I'm missing an obvious solution, or my read model needs improvement.

Comment: would batching the processing of events which cause the updates help? ie use a pull model and pull all events which require an update of the read model and do the update in a single go. Effectively then you can have the update process running continuously applying the updates in batches. Just a thought...

Comment: i suppose that could work if i batched up the changes, and only played the most recent or applicable ones... however eventual consistency would be really really exaggerated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think when you expect one user to be a member of 10s of thousands of groups, the model you have chosen is wrong. You need to remove the list of groups from the user document and stick to the relational model, only keeping group ids. Imagine your groups will need some more attributes than names and you will face the same issue again. And again.

Comment: So you're suggestion is to either re-design the read model, or to use a relational model in a document database...? I think the first is the only one that makes sense, given my read model *needs* to show the group's attributes. I think using a read model that has to somehow fetch each group's attributes would be counter-productive to *having* a read model, which is meant to simplify and improve read performance.

Comment: Having a read model does not automatically mean it has to be completely flat. I realize the constaints you have using the document db but still you can obtain group data from a bunch of group ids. I like denormalizing models with CQRS but this is a typical sample where denormalization sucks.

Comment: fair enough. i will look at remodelling this object